# Turn off image smoothing in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I realize this is probably a duplicate question of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582721/rendering-images-pixelated-with-openlayers-3.

However, there hasn't been a response or comments.  So, thought I'd ask it as well while providing a bit code.

I'm modifying/updating a web page that displays PNG images of various weather-related elements (e.g. temperature) to use OpenLayers 3 instead of 2 as OpenLayers will allow us to use its additional features.  My customer needs the actual pixels displayed upon zooming in versus smoothed.  In OpenLayers 2, I just needed to add the image-rendering CSS, i.e.

```
.olTileImage {
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
    image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;  /* IE (non-standard property) */
}
```

However, if I attempt to do the same thing on the .ol-viewport, .ol-unselectable, img, and canvas classes/elements, nothing happens and the image is still smoothed when zooming in.

This is how I'm declaring the layer:

```
fcstoverlay = new ol.layer.Image({
    type: 'overlay',
    opacity: 0.5,
    title: 'Forecast',
    name: 'imgforecast',

    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: "images/ndfd/conus/mercator/maxt_2016020200.png",
        imageSize: [3328, 2048],
        imageExtent: [-15028131.257, 1878516.407,-6887893.493, 6887893.493],
        projection: ovProj

    }),
    visible: true

});
```

The layer loads just fine, but zooming in displays a smoothed/anti-aliased image which I need to be turned off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenLayers 3 uses a canvas renderer by default. With that renderer, it is easy to achieve what you want, by setting the `imageSmoothingEnabled` property of the canvas context to `false` before the map image is composed. The snippet below assumes that your `map` variable holds your `ol.Map` instance.

```js
map.on('precompose', function(evt) {
  evt.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
});
```

Comment: That worked!  Interestingly, after a day of searching for an answer and then posting this question, I arrived at nearly the same answer using 'precompose' on the layer instead of the whole map.  But I wasn't sure if that was the best solution.  Using 'precompose' on the map for this may work better.  As having images with anti-aliasing turned off for external customers could be important to a good number of developers, could something like this be added as a renderer option in OL3?  It certainly would've saved a day of my development time.

Comment: Well, thanks to your question (and my answer), it is now documented at least :-).

Comment: After an update to OL 4.2.0 this feature stopped working! It was working in 4.1.1

Comment: Works fine for me at 4.2.0. Maybe make sure you're using Canvas and not WebGL renderer, i.e. evt.context is not null and is a CanvasRenderingContext2D.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Thank you both for your detailed question and answer. It helped me a lot in the process to achieve a pixelated view of weather radar data via openlayers 3. I will just add a small bonus information.

When I first added ahocevar answer it did not work. By going through my script line by line I figured out, that the canvas settings is ignored if the method “ol.proj.transform” is used in “ol.view”.

Originally my script included the following map view definition:

```
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform(CenterCoordinates, 'EPSG:32632', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: ZoomLevel
    })
```

When I changed it to the following I achieve a pixelated view:

```
view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:32632',
    center: CenterCoordinates,
    zoom: ZoomLevel
    })
```

So, the answer from ahocevar works perfect for me as well, just not together with “ol.proj.transform”.